# For a given string(2 or 3 word) in a .txt file and print the whole line.

Tags: text-processing, grep, pattern-matching

My `.txt` file contains these kind of content :

```
The Law and Lawyers of Pickwick, by Frank Lockwood                 21214
Frankenstein, by Mary Wollstonecraft                               20
```

The first string is book name,second is author and the last one is book number. I want to print the whole line when someone search with the author name.I tried using grep.

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOKFILE="/home/sk/GUTINDEX.ALL"
author=$1
if [[ -z "$author" ]]; then 
echo -n "Author name : "
read author
fi
grep $author $BOOKFILE
```

**If I run this and search for *Frank Lockwood* it prints both the lines.But I want to print the line when the entire input string match(both the first name and last name)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOKFILE="/home/sk/GUTINDEX.ALL"
author=$@
if [[ -z "$author" ]]; then 
    read -rp "Author name: " author
fi
grep "$author" "$BOOKFILE"
```

If you run it as:

```
$ ./script Frank Lockwood
```

You are setting positional parameter 1 to `Frank` and parameter 2 to `Lockwood`.  Parameter 2 is not in use in your script.  `$@` is an array that will represent all positional parameters.

Also if you are to allow `read` to set your `author` variable to a string with whitespace it will fail on the grep line without quoting `author`.